Websockets not connecting
I am trying to connect to a websocket via @microsoft/signalr but I keep receiving this one error:
Error: WebSocket failed to connect. The connection could not be found on the server, either the endpoint may not be a SignalR endpoint, the connection ID is not present on the server, or there is a proxy blocking WebSockets. If you have multiple servers check that sticky sessions are enabled.
    at webSocket.onclose (C:\Webstorm Projects\AccountCreator\node_modules\@microsoft\signalr\dist\cjs\WebSocketTransport.js:110:28)
    at WebSocket.onClose (C:\Webstorm Projects\AccountCreator\node_modules\ws\lib\event-target.js:136:16)
    at WebSocket.emit (node:events:519:28)
    at WebSocket.emitClose (C:\Webstorm Projects\AccountCreator\node_modules\ws\lib\websocket.js:236:12)
    at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:633:28)
    at ClientRequest.emit (node:events:519:28)
    at emitAbortNT (node:_http_client:430:7)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:81:21)```

My current code is this:
const signalR = require('@microsoft/signalr');

const connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
    .withUrl('https://realtime-signalr.roblox.com/userhub', {
        transport: signalR.HttpTransportType.WebSockets,
        skipNegotiation: true
    })
    .build().start();

